# For the density function $f_\theta (x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}$, how can we find the product distribution, $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a sequence of iid random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ following the pdf:

$$
f_\theta (x) = \theta x^{\theta-1}
$$

for $\theta >0$ and $0 <x<1$.

I would like to find the distribution of:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n X_i
$$

Is there an easy way to do this? I know one method is to first find the distribution of $X_1X_2$, then find the product distribution of $X_1X_2$ and $X_3$. Is there an easier way than doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach is to consider the PDF of the transformed random variable $$Y_i = -\log X_i,$$ and conclude $Y_i \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is a rate parameter.  Consequently, $$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i = \exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right),$$ and we can now exploit the fact that the sum of iid exponential random variables is gamma distributed; i.e., $$\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n,\theta).$$  The final step is to transform the gamma PDF to recover the product distribution.  I have left the details as an exercise.